# How do you set muxer options in libavformat?

Tags: ffmpeg, libavformat

I'm trying to use the libavformat muxer "hlsenc.c".... Looking through the code of the muxers, it looks like muxers support paramaters via the AVOption mechanism... For example, the hlsenc.c muxer supports an AVOption parameter called "hls_time"...

I'm using av_guess_format("hls",NULL,NULL) to find the appropriate output format, but how do you set these options?

(it seems like all the samples on the internet are setting options on a codec... I want to set options on a muxer).

Comment: I've seen you before!

Answer (score 3):

Muxer options can be passed to the second argument of [`avformat_write_header`](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/4.0/group__lavf__encoding.html#ga18b7b10bb5b94c4842de18166bc677cb)

Answer (score 2):

1. use `avformat_alloc_output_context2()` to guess the format for you.
2. then use `avio_open2()` to open the files. `avio_open2()` is the "modern way" your are looking for.

As you can see, it has the `options` parameter.

```
int avio_open2( AVIOContext **s,
                const char *url,
                int flags,
                const AVIOInterruptCB *int_cb,
                AVDictionary **options ); // \o/
```

Comment: `AVDictionary options` in `avio_open2()` go to (are applied to) `URLContext` and `ffurl_connect()`. That is, they are for connection and protocol. AFAICT, not for the muxer.